# Setting Transformation Point On Scaling QGraphicsItem

Tags: python, pyqt6

I am having an issue here.

In the given code, The animation and transformations are working perfectly. However, I want the set the transformation point.

According to me, I have to set `.setTransformationOriginPoint(item.boundingRect().center()` however, it looks like the transformations are taking place from top left.

I even tried setting the point manually but still it didn't work.

Here is the code:

```
from typing import Any
from PyQt6.QtCore import QPointF, QSequentialAnimationGroup, Qt, pyqtSignal
from PyQt6.QtGui import QColor, QEnterEvent, QMouseEvent , QTransform
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QGraphicsColorizeEffect, QGraphicsScene, QGraphicsView, QMainWindow, QWidget
from functools import partial
from PyQt6.QtSvgWidgets import QGraphicsSvgItem

from typing import Any, Callable
from PyQt6.QtCore import QEasingCurve, QPoint, QPropertyAnimation, QRect, QVariantAnimation
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QGraphicsOpacityEffect, QWidget

class Animation:
    def variantAnimation(startValue: Any , endValue: Any , duration: int , callback: Callable) -> QVariantAnimation:
        animation = QVariantAnimation()

        animation.setStartValue(startValue)

        animation.setEndValue(endValue)

        animation.setDuration(duration)

        animation.setEasingCurve(QEasingCurve.Type.InOutQuad)

        animation.valueChanged.connect(callback)

        return animation


class Rounded_Jolly_Button(QGraphicsView):
    clicked = pyqtSignal()
    
    def __init__(self , parent: QWidget , location: str):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.location = location

        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: #2E3440; border-radius: 22px")

        self.setFixedSize(45 , 45)

        self.setCursor(Qt.CursorShape.PointingHandCursor)

        self._scene = QGraphicsScene()

        self.setScene(self._scene)

        self._scene.setSceneRect(0 , 0 , 40 , 40)

        self.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarPolicy.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)

        self.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarPolicy.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)

        self.setStyles()

    def setStyles(self):
        color = QGraphicsColorizeEffect()

        color.setColor(QColor("#D8DEE9"))

        svg = QGraphicsSvgItem("./assets/google.svg")

        svg.setAcceptHoverEvents(True)

        svg.setPos(10 , 10)

        svg.setGraphicsEffect(color)

        self._scene.addItem(svg)

        svg.setTransformOriginPoint(svg.boundingRect().center())

        self.animations = QSequentialAnimationGroup()

        self.animations.addAnimation(Animation.variantAnimation(QPointF(1.0 , 1.0) , QPointF(1.25 , 0.75) , 270 , partial(self.updateTransform , svg)))

        self.animations.addAnimation(Animation.variantAnimation(QPointF(1.25 , 0.75) , QPointF(.75 , 1.25) , 90 , partial(self.updateTransform , svg)))

        self.animations.addAnimation(Animation.variantAnimation(QPointF(.75 , 1.25) , QPointF(1.15 , .85) , 90 , partial(self.updateTransform , svg)))

        self.animations.addAnimation(Animation.variantAnimation(QPointF(1.15 , 0.85) , QPointF(.95 , 1.05) , 135 , partial(self.updateTransform , svg)))

        self.animations.addAnimation(Animation.variantAnimation(QPointF(.95 , 1.05) , QPointF(1.05 , 0.95) , 90 , partial(self.updateTransform , svg)))

        self.animations.addAnimation(Animation.variantAnimation(QPointF(1.05 , 0.95) , QPointF(1 , 1) , 225 , partial(self.updateTransform , svg)))

    def enterEvent(self, event: QEnterEvent) -> None:
        self.animations.start()

        return super().enterEvent(event)

    def mousePressEvent(self, ev: QMouseEvent) -> None:
        if(ev.button() == Qt.MouseButton.LeftButton):
            self.clicked.emit()

        return super().mousePressEvent(ev)

    def updateTransform(self , target: QGraphicsSvgItem , newValue: Any):
        target.setTransform(QTransform().scale(newValue.x() , newValue.y()))


def window():
    app = QApplication([])

    window = QMainWindow()

    parent = QWidget()

    button = Rounded_Jolly_Button(parent , None)

    window.setCentralWidget(parent)

    window.show()
    
    exit(app.exec())
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
   window()
```

Note: `./assets/google.svg` contains an svg downloaded from [Font Awesome](https://fontawesome.com/v5.15/icons/google?style=brands) and resized to 20x20 pixel

Comment: Please try to avoid adding blank lines for each line of code, they actually make your code less readable.

Comment: Oh I see! But for me, the code looks more cleaner and readable. (People have different feelings for different things)

Comment: Of course everybody has their own tastes for coding styles and you could obviously use any style you like if it suits you, but this is a common place, and we should all try to adhere to conventions shared by the majority of people when providing code in questions and answers, especially if they are considered standard. Specifically, Python's [PEP8 suggests](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id19) to use blank lines in functions *sparingly*, and only to indicate (separate) logical sections. Also, your imports could be more concise. and there are both duplicate and unused imports.

Comment: Yeah. I have been also told the very same thing (not to leave so many lines) by many people. But whenever I am remove lines, The code looks like a butter spreaded over a pancake.

Comment: And as for the unused imports, I had the template build so I just copy and pasted and created an MRE. Thanks for providing that link ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Transformations are always created with an origin point set at `(0, 0)`, and, when using `setTransform()`, the item's `transformOriginPoint` is ignored, since it's only used for the internal `setRotation` and `setScale` functions.

Internally, when a rotation or scale is set to a QGraphicsItem, the transformation is applied in the following way:

- create a new transformation;
- translate it to the origin point;
- apply the rotation;
- apply the scale;
- restore the translation back;

Since you need to do an asymmetrical scaling (which `setScale` doesn't provide), you need to do the same for the new transformation.

```
    def updateTransform(self , target: QGraphicsSvgItem , newValue: Any):
        origin = target.transformOriginPoint()
        transform = QTransform().translate(origin.x(), origin.y())
        transform.scale(newValue.x(), newValue.y())
        transform.translate(-origin.x(), -origin.y())
        target.setTransform(transform)
```