# QTransform not respecting QGraphicsItem.transformOriginPoint when using QGraphicsItem.setTransform to rotate. Is this a bug or working as intended?

Tags: pyside6

I noticed behavior that may be a bug, but would like feedback before posting it in the Qt bug tracker as I may be misunderstanding the intended behavior.

The issue is getting different results when rotating a QGraphicsItem using the .setRotation convenience function versus the .setTransform method and passing a QTransform.
The QTransform method appears to not respect the transform origin point as set with QGraphicsItem.setTransformOriginPoint.

Here is a minimal working example that demonstrates the different behavior.

```
from PySide6 import QtGui
from PySide6.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QGraphicsRectItem,
    QGraphicsScene,
    QGraphicsView,
    QMainWindow,
    QPushButton,
    QVBoxLayout,
    QWidget,
)


class MyWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.central_widget = QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.central_widget)
        self.central_widget.setLayout(self.layout)

        self.view = QGraphicsView()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.view)
        self.scene = QGraphicsScene(self)
        self.view.setScene(self.scene)

        self.rectangle = QGraphicsRectItem(0, 0, 500, 275)
        pen = QtGui.QPen()
        pen.setWidth(25)
        pen.setColor("Yellow")
        self.rectangle.setPen(pen)

        self.scene.addItem(self.rectangle)

        self.button_with_QTransform = QPushButton(
            text="Rotate Using QTransform",
            parent=self,
        )
        self.button_without_QTransform = QPushButton(
            "Rotate without QTransform",
            self,
        )
        self.layout.addWidget(self.button_with_QTransform)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.button_without_QTransform)
        self.button_with_QTransform.clicked.connect(
            self.transform_rectangle_with_QTransform
        )
        self.button_without_QTransform.clicked.connect(
            self.transform_rectangle_without_QTransform
        )
        self.rectangle.setTransformOriginPoint(self.rectangle.boundingRect().center())
        self.current_rotation = 0

    def transform_rectangle_with_QTransform(self):
        self.current_rotation += 10
        transform = QtGui.QTransform()
        transform.rotate(self.current_rotation)
        self.rectangle.setTransform(transform)

    def transform_rectangle_without_QTransform(self):
        self.current_rotation += 10
        self.rectangle.setRotation(self.current_rotation)


def main():
    app = QApplication()
    window = MyWindow()
    window.show()
    window.showMaximized()
    app.exec()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setting Transformation Point On Scaling QGraphicsItem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69436810/setting-transformation-point-on-scaling-qgraphicsitem)

Comment: Also [Resizing and rotating a QGraphicsItem results in odd shape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32186798/resizing-and-rotating-a-qgraphicsitem-results-in-odd-shape/32188957#32188957). Then read the [Transformations](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qgraphicsitem.html#transformations) docs.

Comment: I see.
I was also using QTransform to apply a translation, so I didn't realize I would have to:
```
origin = my_graphics_item.boundingRect().center()
transform = QTransform()
transform.translate(origin.x(), origin.y())
transform.rotateRadians(0.5)
transform.scale(1.2, 1.2)
transform.translate(-origin.x(), -origin.y())

transform.translate(x, y)  # where x and y are the actual values I want the item translated by

my_graphics_item.setTransform(transform)
```

Comment: Please note that comments have limited formatting capabilities (no triple backticks). In any case, consider that the transform origin point is only valid for the simple QGraphicsItem transformations (scale, rotate), and the complete transform takes into account all transformations; the documentation explains that, but it's not very clear about the relation between these transforms (basic rotation/scale and complete transform). If the above links do solve your issue, I suggest you to accept the duplicate proposal.